# Linux software for drawing star charts

Tags: linux, library, drawing, charts, astronomy

I would like to produce some astronomical star charts; something like this:

http://astropixels.com/messier/summer.html

or the one [here](http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/9926/starchartwinterdr7.gif).  Most star charts are set for the Northern Hemisphere; I'm in the Southern, and would like to have some printable charts for my latitude and longitude, which contain the objects I want, and in which all the objects are appropriately labelled.

There are many astronomy software systems, and libraries for different programming languages, but I haven't yet found one which creates nicely labelled charts.  And as I say it has to run under Linux, which is my preferred OS.  (Well, in fact, it's my *only* OS).

Are there any such systems or libraries?

Comment: is [Stellarium](http://stellarium.org/) something similar you are looking for?

Comment: I don't know such a tool, but would suggest you have a look in this list: https://packages.debian.org/testing/science/science-astronomy It contains the packages in debian that relate to astronomy. I would be surprised if there is nothing in there that suits your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[kstars](http://edu.kde.org/kstars) has a way to create charts. One of the authors of kstars has written a [blog post](https://kstars.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/astro-scripting-using-kstars-d-bus-interface/) about it. Unfortunately, the links to the charts are not working right now.

Edit: Found the logbook project [on github](https://github.com/kstar/logbook).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [Cartes du Ciel](https://www.ap-i.net/skychart/en/start), it has a huge catalogue and the charts are very good looking, you can also print them in paper. And, of course, it runs in Linux (rpm and deb packages available).